# Displaying values in multiple instance of the same form in C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a winform in my C# application. This winform has some controls, a send button and list view to display values. I have internal logic which sends a request and the retrieved values are displayed in the list view. So If I open the form, send request and the values are enlisted in the listview of the form. This form is left open.  When another instance of the form is open, request is sent, the values are retrieved but the values are getting displayed in the listview of the first instance of the form.
How can I fix this?

Comment: From where you retrieved the information? from service? are you using same instance of data in both forms?

Comment: Please post the relevant part of the code.

Comment: Provide us more information please.